# View attached SCSI devices under Windows SBS SP2

Tags: windows-server-2008, scsi, hp-storageworks

I've a problematic HP StorageWorks autoloader drive running on a Windows Server Standard FE SP2 (aka: Windows SBS 2008) box.

As my first port of call in terms of problem diagnosis, I thought I'd check that the device was actually showing up on the SCSI chain. (As you can perhaps tell, I'm from a Unix background.)

As such, I'm just wondering if there's an easy built-in means of viewing the devices on the SCSI chain, or whether I need to use a HP specific tool to scan for the specific device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the following utility from Microsoft should do the trick - http://download.microsoft.com/download/win2000ddk/utility/1.0/nt5xp/en-us/rescan1.exe.

Comment: That looks like it should do the trick. (Think I'll wait to run it outside work hours, that said.) :-)

Comment: Probably a smart move as SCSI scans can sometimes involve/result in disconnecting the devices being scanned.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. :-)